# is there a way to know java packages in a jar file?

Tags: java, jar

Is there any way to know the packages of a .jar file as I want to use "gtranslateapi-1.0" but not getting the package or class names in it.

I have also added it to my libraries in netbeans 8.0

You can see it here: https://code.google.com/p/java-google-translate-text-to-speech/downloads/list

please help, thanks in advance !!

Comment: in netbeans you can see classes

Comment: Something like this? `jar tf the.jar|grep '\.class$'`

Comment: You can browse the content with any zip tool.

Comment: Or you could just unzip the jar file and see it for yourself.

Comment: [Here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/c/Downloadcomgoogleapitranslate10jar.htm) you can see the content of the jar.

Comment: @NishantSinghal you can accept if you got the answer

Answer (score 1):

jar is just a zip.so if you want to know what is packed into a jar file, you may unzip it (using either your favourite zip tool or jar itself e.g jar -t to list the contents). hint jar without args gives you a list of options

Answer (score 1):

in netbeans you can easily see packages and classes .or you can rename .jar to .zip and open in compress program like winrar

in netbeans you can expand jar easily.add jar to libries and expand it .this is your jar file

[image]